# Azure Chatbot fails with "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - cosmosClient.databases.createIfNotExists" while connecting to CosmosDB

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bot-service, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am extremely new to Azure Bot Services and the Azure platform as a whole. 
I am trying to create a Chatbot using node.js but I am getting the below error while trying to connect to CosmosDB.

The bot was running fine before I added the below code to connect to CosmosDB.

*Any help or guidance on this would be appreciated!*

*P.S. - I have added the '@azure/cosmos' package and the code runs without any error if I just remove the try-catch segment.*

**Code for connecting to CosmosDB:**

```
var async=require("async"); 
var await=require("await"); 

const CosmosClientInterface = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;
const databaseId = "ToDoList"; 
const containerId = "custInfo"; 

const endpoint = "<Have provided the Endpoint URL here>";
const authKey = "<Have provided the AuthKey here>";

const cosmosClient = new CosmosClientInterface({
    endpoint: endpoint,
    auth: {
      masterKey: authKey
    },
    consistencyLevel: "Session"
  });

async function readDatabase() {
   const { body: databaseDefinition } = await cosmosClient.database(databaseId).read();
   console.log(`Reading database:\n${databaseDefinition.id}\n`);
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
Sat Jan 12 2019 03:40:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:40
async function readDatabase() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:40
async function readDatabase() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't await without being in an `async` function.

Dump all your code into a `async function main(){}` method, then call `main().catch((err) => console.log(err));` or some similar thing to start the promise and handle errors.

You can see a sample of that kind of pattern here in this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-js/blob/master/samples/ChangeFeed/app.js#L33

--- EDIT 1 ---

Here's your sample rewritten with Promises:

```
const CosmosClientInterface = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;
const databaseId = "ToDoList"; 
const containerId = "custInfo"; 

const endpoint = "<Have provided the Endpoint URL here>";
const authKey = "<Have provided the AuthKey here>";

const cosmosClient = new CosmosClientInterface({
    endpoint: endpoint,
    auth: {
      masterKey: authKey
    },
    consistencyLevel: "Session"
  });

cosmosClient.database(databaseId).read().then(({body: databaseDefinition}) => {
   console.log(`Reading database:\n${databaseDefinition.id}\n`);
}).catch((err) {
   console.err("Something went wrong" + err);
});
```

For your sample above, you don't need to import async/await, they are keywords in JavaScript now.

Here's a blog post that compares and contrasts Async/Await and Promises: https://hackernoon.com/should-i-use-promises-or-async-await-126ab5c98789

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris!

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris! But now I am getting an error while trying to define an async function. I get an error saying "Unexpected token 'function' ". I tried with nodejs versions 6.9.1 and 10.14.1 but getting the same error on both. While searching online I understood that some nodejs versions don't support async/await and we should use 'Babel'. But I couldn't understand the whole process. Is there something simple that I'm just missing here OR can we connect to CosmosDB without the use of 'async'?

Comment: You can also just use Promises, without worrying about async (Cosmos samples all use Async because it is shorter... :))

Node 8 and above supports async, though, so 10.14.1 should be cool.

Comment: Could you modify your question with your new code and I can take a look?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have updated the question with new code and error message. Please have a look when you have time. Also, could you point me towards any guide on connecting to Cosmos using promises and without async? (just in case this async/await problem isn't solved).

Comment: Thanks for the update Chris! I'm still facing a lot of other issues but I'm marking this as the Accepted answer as it did solve the initial question. I'm working on the other problems that I'm facing and will post a new question if necessary.